# Proper way to express "He disappeared them"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

While watching an early episode of the TV show, "The Blacklist," one of the characters used the phrase:

> We got the list of the people he disappeared.

I'm sure they meant the people the bad guy helped to disappear, but shouldn't "he disappeared" mean that he, the bad guy disappeared?

What, exactly, did the character mean when he said that and what would be a grammatically correct way to say it?

Comment: tidbit: to disappear people became common when it was used to explain that people had disappeared in Argentina during the junta in the seventies. Before that, it was not used like this.

Comment: Apart from me remembering Chile (probably because I didn’t live in the uk during the Thatcher era), that’s where it comes from.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look up [disappear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disappear) in the dictionary, you'll see that it has a transitive meaning:

> to cause the disappearance of

This is exactly the meaning that's being used in the sentence you quote:

> We got the list of the people he *caused the disappearance of*.

Usually, this transitive use of **disappear**, especially **disappearing** other people, has very sinister overtones.  You'll see it used with secret police in totalitarian dictatorships, for example, or maybe with mafia-like criminal organizations.  The implication is that the person or organization doing the **disappearing** has enough power and resources that they aren't just killing their enemies, they're invisibly snatching them away and destroying all evidence of their existence.

---

Edited to add:

I wrote "usually" above about the political implications of the transitive **disappear**, but the more I thought about it, the more I think that it is *almost exclusively* used in this case.  Wikipedia says this about the word [disappeared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappeared_(disambiguation)):

> The term **disappeared** most commonly refers to the victims of [forced disappearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_disappearance).

Where [forced disappearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_disappearance) has a particular meaning in international human rights law of a government's secret abduction, detention, and presumed execution of political enemies without a fair trial. If applied to an actor other than a government agent, it would imply that person belongs to an organization with power rivaling that of a national government.

This matches my gut sense of the transitive **disappear** as well.  A native-speaking mother would *not* say to her child, "You **disappeared** your entire dinner - good job!"  But you would read something like, "After German reunification and the declassification of Stasi documents, some of the relatives of the **disappeared** have finally learned the fate of their loved ones."